# Passing data from selected item to viewmodel in WinRT

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm-light, winrt-xaml

I am currently writing an application in WinRT where i need to pass an id from a selected item in a listview back to my viewmodel. My listview has an Observable collection as an itemsource so there will be a different id for each item in the listview.

my Xaml code look similar to this

```
    <ListView Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding VacationOverviewDisplay}"  >
                <WinRtBehaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <Win8nl_Behavior:EventToCommandBehavior Event="SelectionChanged"   
                                              Command="DetailsCommand"
                                              CommandParameter="{Binding Path=DontKnow, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </WinRtBehaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Text="{Binding VacationStart, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='{}{0:dd MMM yyyy}' }" Margin="20,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Text="{Binding VacationEnd, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='{}{0:dd MMM yyyy}' }" Margin="20,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="id" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Text="{Binding VacationRequestId}" Margin="20,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusView}" Margin="50,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="Title: " Margin="50,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding VacationCommentUser}" Margin="5,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            </ListView>
```

I am using the WinRTBehaviors to mimic the EventToCommand behavior but i have no idea how i should get a certain parameter from an item in my listview back to my viewmodel. for the Mvvm i am using MvvmLight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a property in a view model then bind it to SelectedItem in your list view like this:

```
SelectedItem={Binding MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay}
```

That's all. Whenever a user changed a value, your property will be updated.

Comment: Thank you this was the problem idd, bit stupid but think i wont forget now :)

Answer (score 1):

Bind Selected Item To a Property in your ViewModel

```
<ListView Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding VacationOverviewDisplay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVacation, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `SelectedValuePath` for extracting `Id` from `SelectedItem`:

```
<ListView Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding VacationOverviewDisplay}"
                          SlectedValuePath="Id" 
                          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedVacationId, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyListBox, Path=SelectedItem}"
```

(You'll have to give your ListBox an x:Name value.)